# How do I get my AWS access key and secret key?

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS noob here.
I've authenticated using profile MyProfile (`aws sso login --profile MyProfile`).

I can issue `aws configure list` which returns:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile              MyProfile              env    ['AWS_PROFILE', 'AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE']
access_key     ****************4G7M              sso   
secret_key     ****************lge5              sso   
    region                eu-west-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

How do I obtain the access_key & secret_key so that I can use them in a script?
I've tried `aws configure get aws_secret_access_key --profile MyProfile` but that doesn't return anything and it has an exit code of 1.

Comment: You should almost never explicitly use keys. If you use the CLI or any SDK with the default credentials provider, it will work without any configuration via its auto-detection of authentication methods.

Comment: I've inherited some code that runs in GitHub Actions and which uses the access key & secret key. I'm trying to debug that locally, hence why I need those values.

Comment: It's an easy fix to just remove the code that explicitly requires keys. It will continue to work on github actions as well as should start working local as well. If you still want to go down this path, look in ~/.aws/sso/cache/.